# What is the default python version used by jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv

I am looking at jenkins failure, when running its "tests" stage, and noticed that the creation of the python virtual environment did not have a python version used.  I am wondering from that if the default version is the system version (2.7) or if the default version is based on the [jenkins slave scripts](https://github.com/PatientPopInc/aws/blob/master/ami/jenkins-slave/scripts/001-python-install.sh).

I've added in pre-commit-hooks into my pycharm copy and those pass without issues (using python 3.6).  When I've pushed my code up and jenkins runs its tests, I get errors that point me to the direction that the default python is not 3.6 (does not recognize f-strings)

This is one of the current tests in the jenkins file:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install flake8
flake8 --ignore=E501 onboarding/ tests/
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins does not come with Python. This completely depends on what version `virtualenv` installs (otherwise, it would be your operating system's python version).